# Laravel: retrieving unassigned records from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am building a simple attendance monitoring system with Laravel. I have two related tables `teachers` table and the `grade_levels` table.

here's the table structure for both

**Teachers Table**

`id(PK)`

`advisory_class(FK)` -> references id on `grade_levels` table

`teacher_name`

**Grade Levels Table**

`id(PK)`

`grade_level`

`section`

what I am trying to do is retrieve all the record from `grade_levels` table which are not yet assigned to a teacher from the `teachers table`

how do I do query this with Laravel??

I tried doing a join query, but I get the records with assigned teachers.

`$teachers = DB::table('teachers')
                    ->join('grade_levels','teachers.advisory_class', '=', 'grade_levels.id')
                    ->select('teachers.*','grade_levels.grade_lvl','grade_levels.section')
                    ->get();`

am I missing something on this query?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You need a `leftJoin()` and `whereNull()`. Or a `whereNotIn()` with a subquery. `doesntHave()` might also work, if you set up your model relations correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all rows from parent table A that have no matches in the child table B, the query should look like:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.fk = a.pk
WHERE b.fk IS NULL
```

So in your case it woul be:

```
$gradeLevels = DB::table('grade_levels')
    ->leftJoin('teachers','teachers.advisory_class', '=', 'grade_levels.id')
    ->whereNull('teachers.advisory_class')
    ->select('grade_levels.*')
    ->get();
```

Note that it doesn't make any sense to select anything from the `teachers` table, since you are searching for "grade levels" with no teacher assigned.

Using models, this might also work:

```
$gradeLevels = GradeLevel::whereNotIn('id', Teacher::select(advisory_class))->get();
```